# How do I prepend/append (concatenate) data to each row in a MySQL result or data set?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Here's a query I'm making:

```
SELECT sku FROM items
```

With results of:

```
18972 
81771
29883
```

I want to add data to the beginning and end of each row that is returned so it looks something like this:

```
sku18972a
sku81771a
sku29883a
```

What do I need to add to my `SELECT` statement to do what I need?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SELECT CONCAT('sku', sku, 'a') AS new_sku FROM items
```